# XBox One: Access a UNC share through a UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, unc, xbox

Is XBox One capable of accessing UNC shares? Specifically, does a code like this:

```
   StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"\\myComputer\MySharedFolder");
   StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("MyFile.mp4");
   var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
   myMediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
```

Work on XBox One?

Comment: According to the document here [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations), it should work but you need to add capabilities for it. You can try it first.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I actually did. This code works on Windows, but when deployed on an actual XBOX One the GetFolderFromPathAsync line throws an ArgumentException with message "value was not within expected range". That's why I asked the question here actually.
All capabilities are properly added.

It's weird that there is no proper documentation for what does and doesn't work on XBOX.

Comment: That's strange, UNC is not listed in [UWP features not yet supported on Xbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/extension-sdks/uwp-limitations-on-xbox) . I'll ask the xbox team about this.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT That would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There might be some time delay. I'll update here as soon as I get response.